# axios post request is sending a request header of Content-Type: multipart/form-data resulting in undefined req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, multipartform-data

I have a form that uses axios to send a post request. The problem is that the request is being sent with a header of Content-Type: multipart/form-data. My nodejs api does not like this and gives me an undefined req.body.

I have other forms that use the same techniques and they work and the header is as expected with: Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

The form that is posting Content-Type: multipart/form-data does not have any images. Just text input fields.

If I try to set the form headers manually they are ignored. Why would one form send standard 'application/json' and another form send 'multipart/form-data'?

Here is the form in pug:

```
form.form.form-send-cert-data
                    .form__group
                        label.form__label(for='name') Recipients Name
                        input#name.form__input(type='text', required, name='name')
                    .form__group
                        label.form__label(for='email') Recipient Email
                        input#email.form__input(type='text', required, name='email')
                    .form__group
                        label.form__label(for='plantId') Plant
                        select(name='plantId', id='plantId')
                            each val in ['5f1133ca79232fab1ffe5be4' , '5f113d3944221b47f577c239' , '5f113e019f4aa448a253ed87']
                                option=val
                    .form__group
                        label.form__label(for='message') Message
                        input#message.form__input(type='text', required, name='message')
                    .form__group.right
                        button.btn.btn--small.btn--green Send Certificate
```

Here is how I prep the form data for the post:

```
addCertificateForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('name', document.getElementById('name').value);
    form.append('email', document.getElementById('email').value);
    form.append('message', document.getElementById('message').value);
    form.append('plantId', document.getElementById('plantId').value);
    console.log('-Send Certificate-');
    sendCertificate(form, 'data');
  });
```

Here is sendCertificate.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { showAlert } from './alerts';

export const sendCertificate = async (data, type) => {
  console.log('sendCertificate.js');
  try {
    const url = '/api/v1/certificates/send';
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url,
      data,
    });

    if (res.data.status === 'success') {
      showAlert('success', `${type.toUpperCase()} sent successfully!`);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    showAlert('error', err.response.data.message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't sending any files that must be sent using FormData you can easily build an object to pass to axios which will send as json

```
addCertificateForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const postData = {};
  const keys = ['name', 'email', 'message', 'plantId'];

  keys.forEach(k => postData[k] = document.getElementById(k).value)

  sendCertificate(postData, 'data');
});
```

Note I haven't used Axios for years and don't remember if you need to set json content-type header or if it is set by default

Comment: That worked! That bug was a weekend killer but now I can move on. charlietfl your the best!